# SQL Oracle: selecting all data and then multiply two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to display all data from a table, take two columns and multiply them and place the result in a new column at the end. Can I use the '*' and then multiply or do I have to select each column individually?

This displays my desired result using the JustLee database in OracleLive but I have to select each column.

```
select order#, item#, isbn, quantity, paideach, quantity * paideach as "Item Total" 
from orderitems;
```

Is it possible to combine the '*' and then multiply two columns? Below is around what I am looking for.

```
select *, quantity * paideach as "Item Total"
from orderitems;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should correct your second query in the following way:

```sql
select orderitems.*, quantity * paideach as "Item Total"
from orderitems;
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this the only way to do it, besides Julia's whos also works. I am taking Oracle at a community college in ch2 and it talks about aliases as "select columnName as "Whatever Name" from tablename;" but it never mentions this method of "orderitems.*"

Comment: You can always use full table name instead of the alias, although alias in many cases is more practical. I did not see the answer posted before I posted mine. Also, in this particular case an alias (or full table name) is necessary before the "*" only. Since quantity and paideach are not ambiguous, the alias is not necessary in front of them.

Comment: @DRod  alias is a just a different name for something.  What you are describing is a column alias and what we are utilizing here is a table alias. Besides the case in your question, table aliases are often necessary when you are joining two tables which have identical column names so you need to be explicit about which table you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Add an alias to the table:

```
select o.*, quantity * paideach as "Item Total"
from orderitems o;
```

Comment: You were 10 minutes earlier, so deserve at least an upvote and to be the accepted answer.